# Layout design problem

Tags: android, layout

I was designing a layout but encountered a problem. Somehow, it has a empty space on the right of my tablelayout and I can't fill it. If anyone has an idea, then would you help me please?

Below is my layout xml and screenshot to show what exactly happes; by the way, the reason why I am using tablelayout is in order to put some items there using interaction with the user.

Thank you in advance

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/header_life_title" android:textSize="20sp" android:text="Life: " android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/header_life_value" android:textSize="20sp" android:text="20" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <Button android:text="Inc." android:id="@+id/header_btn_inc" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="35dp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <Button android:text="Dec." android:id="@+id/header_btn_dec" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="35dp"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Put L." android:id="@+id/header_btn_putLand" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="35dp"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Remove L." android:id="@+id/header_btn_removeLand" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="35sp">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/land_space">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/cardboard">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/layout_menu">
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_creature" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="150dp"></Spinner>
                <Button android:id="@+id/btn_creature" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Cast"></Button>
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_noncreature" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Spinner>
                <Button android:id="@+id/btn_noncreature" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Cast"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/btn_delete" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Del."></Button>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow_cardImage"><![enter image description here][1]/TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow_cardData"></TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow_cardImage2"></TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow_cardData2"></TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
http://imageshack.us/m/52/2443/111iyr.jpg
```

Comment: Isn't that space caused by the LinearLayout instead of the TableLayout?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Caspar. If possible, would you let me know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Dit you try a layout_width="fill_parent" on the last element: Del.? (just a guess)

Comment: Should the buttons/spinners in the second row fill the view?

Comment: just one of them I think, I would go for the smallest one to prevent choping-text at small screens or portrait mode.

Comment: I just changed the layout_width of the last linear layout - whose id is land_space - right before the tablelayout to "fill_parent" and tried it but still doesn't work

Comment: remove match parrent with fillparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `LinearLayout`'s `layout_weight` attribute to force the views inside of it to take up the space left.

Setting the `layout_weight` attribute to **`"1"`** in for all child views will make them take up the remaining space equally:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/layout_menu">
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_creature"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"></Spinner>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_creature"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Cast"></Button>
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_noncreature"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Spinner>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_noncreature"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Cast"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Del."></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

The width of the child views is set to `wrap_content`, so they won't get wider when you change the orientation of the phone, even though the parent has more space horizontally. 
Using `layout_weight` you can set the portion for each child view how much from the parent's remaining space should fill.

For more reference: [`LinearLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, rekaszeru! Now I solved the prblem. Thanks for your help as well, Caspar!

Comment: Wow, I just checked your modified this comment. Thanks for the reference too!